# Biztalk Flat File Schema Tutorial

Tags: biztalk

Is there any good website for Biztalk Flat File Schema Tutorial?

It is because there are many setting in Flat File Schema (e.g. repeating delimiter type, group max occurs etc), which is very hard to understand its exact meaning.

Thanks.

Comment: asking for off-site resources like tutorials are off-topic here

Comment: try Google and YouTube, or try "BizTalk 2013/2016 Recipes - A Problem Solution approach" book.

Answer (score 0):

There are tutorials and walkthroughs in the SDK or MSDN.  Start here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559306.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8894